# HTTP Post MQL4 to php

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

This is a piece of code I am trying to use to `POST` a set of 13 parameter values from the MQL4 script to an external php script, named upload.php

```
   string headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   string data    = "{\"ohlcVectors\":{\"ticker\":\"dax\",\"barIntervalSeconds\":300,\"open\":[6844.2998046875," +
      "6847.7998046875]},\"className\":\"MAIndicator\",\"parameters\":{\"periods\":2}}";

string acceptTypes[1] = {"*/*"};

   int HttpOpen    = InternetOpenA(   "HTTP_Client_Sample", 1, NULL, NULL, 0 );
   int HttpConnect = InternetConnectA( HttpOpen, "127.0.0.1", 7777, NULL, NULL, 3, 0, 1 );
   int HttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA( HttpConnect, "POST", "/tradesheet/upload.php", NULL, NULL, acceptTypes, 0, 1 );
                     HttpSendRequestA( HttpRequest, headers, StringLen( headers ), data, StringLen( data ) );
```

The compiler keeps throwing an error that the **`data`** is an incompatible type. That `data` string was picked up from a site, when I was searching for ways for `MQL4` to send `POST` params to a php. But I need that string `data` to have my own parameter values, but clueless on how to put it in the right format.

I tried searching quite a bit and just cant find anything helpful.

The following is the parameter list that I need to send to upload.php. Can someone please help me arrange in the format that **`HttpSendRequestA()`** is expecting it ?

```
string params[13][13];
params[0][0] = "x1";
params[0][1] = "GOD@GMAIL.com";

params[1][0] = "x2";
params[1][1] = 10000;

params[2][0] = "x3";
params[2][1] = 10000;

params[3][0] = "x4";
params[3][1] = "fxpro";

params[4][0] = "x5";
params[4][1] = "usd";

params[5][0] = "x6";
params[5][1] = 10000;

params[6][0] = "x7";
params[6][1] = 5000;

params[7][0] = "x8";
params[7][1] = 10;

params[8][0] = "x9";
params[8][1] = 10;

params[9][0] = "x10";
params[9][1] = "sdfskfms";

params[10][0] = "x11";
params[10][1] = 232;

params[11][0] = "x12";
params[11][1] = 230;

params[12][0] = "x13";
params[12][1] = "fxpro";
```

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

High chances you are using build 600.
Build 600 supports Unicode and not Ansi anymore.

therefore these are the functions you have to use:

```
InternetOpenW
InternetConnectW
HttpOpenRequestW
HttpSendRequestW
```

see below:

[Mt4 b600 / ghttp.mqh and InternetOpenUrlA() problem](http://forum.mql4.com/60826)